# Web Programming Barcode Printing issue

Tags: angularjs, vb.net, web

In current legacy application (XXX) the Bar-code are printed automatically to Zebra printer. It may be shared path or direct printer location. The system can configure the automatic or manual printing settings (preview) for particular module. Hence during the module execution if the printer is configure, the system will send the command to printer and print the barcode directly.

Issues#
The challenges appeared during the Web Application. In web application, during the execution of the module the web application check the default printer and always prompt printing options and manually print the barcode. 
Need to find a solution how to automatically print the barcode directly through Web application to local printer or shared printers?
Also if the web application is hosted on the Intranet how the access of the shared and local printers can be done during the execution of the module?

Answer (score 0):

How is the web application printing? It sounds like you are using the browser printing functions, which generally can be triggered via Javascript but require user intervention to actually print. I have solved this problem when migrating legacy applications by connecting every printer to the local network directly (many Zebra printers have an Ethernet adapter available) and printing directly from the web application.

I have done this with PHP (pfsockopen($ipaddress,$port) - where $ipaddress is the local printer's static IP address and $port is typically 9100; then fputs() to write the print data) and it should be most possible with most general purpose languages. This works both on internet and intranet, though with internet printers you have to open 9100 (or an alternate port, though typically mapped to 9100 before it gets to the printer) through the routers/firewalls.